# Function that maps a par into the small possible values

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given $N \in \mathbb{N}$, I am looking for a function  $ f: \{1,2,...,N\}^2\rightarrow \{1,2,...,\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\}$ such that:

$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \cdots & f(1,N) \\
f(2,1) & f(2,2) & \cdots & f(2,N) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(N,1) & f(N,2) & \cdots & f(N,N) 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & N \\
2 & N+1 & \cdots & 2N-1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
N & 2N-1 & \cdots & \frac{N(N+1)}{2} 
\end{pmatrix}
$

Note that $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$ and we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
1& =  f(1,1)\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}f(1,2)\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}...\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}f(1,N)=N \\
&\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}f(2,2)\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}f(2,3)\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}...\stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow}f(2,N)=N+(N-1) \\
& \stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow} f(3,3) \stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow} f(3,4) \stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow} ... \stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow} f(3,N) = N + (N-1) + (N-2) \\
& ... \\
& \stackrel{+1}{\rightarrow} f(N,N)=N+(N-1)+(N-2)+...+1=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Can someone find an expression for $f$ that depends only on $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me whether you have a specific pattern in mind and are looking for a functional form for it, or whether you're asking us to find a good way to fill in a pattern. In case it's the former, I don't see what pattern you have in mind, and you should describe it.

Comment: i have edited my post. I want an expression for $f$ depending on its arguments that maps each pair to the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(a,b)=\frac{N(N+1)}2-\frac{(N-\min(a,b))(N-\min(a,b)+1)}2-(N-\max(a,b))\;.
$$

Comment: that was exactly what I wanted! Thanks! May I just ask how did you came up with that?

Comment: @Babado: I focussed on the top right half and used $\min$ and $\max$ to map the other half onto that by symmetry. Then I inverted everything (subtracting the arguments from $N$ and the function value from $N(N+1)/2$), so that the result is the triangular number for the row index plus the column index.